# html: linking two elements without losing their position on the page

Tags: html, positioning

I have two elements (a field and some text) that I would like to link so that no matter how much I shrink the page, the two elements appear next to one another.

I also want for the two elements to remain where they were on the page prior to me encapsulating them in one element.

How can I do this?  (I have tried putting them in a div and a table, both of which push the elements to a new line.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the 2 elements to be next to each other, in the same pixel position on the page, you need to use `position:absolute` and specify a pixel position for each element.

I assume this is what you mean by "link them" together.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant.  I think you meant position:absolute though.  Thanks.

Comment: Yep, you're right! Slip of the mind right there. :)

Mind accepting the answer?